# Ubuntu Software Center fails to launch

Tags: software-center, cinnamon

Everytime I try to launch ubuntu software center it flashes the window and then closes. Even if I try from the terminal. When typing

```
software-center
```

I get this:

```
/usr/bin/software-center:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without
  specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before 
  import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/purchaseview.py:29: 
  PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use 
  gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the 
  right version gets loaded.
    from gi.repository import WebKit2 as webkit
2016-12-13 15:59:47,733 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger -
    WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/
  symbolic_icons.py:23: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without 
  specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') 
  before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, PangoCairo
2016-12-13 15:59:47,790 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - 
    INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2016-12-13 15:59:49,479 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - 
    WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in 
    config file
2016-12-13 15:59:49,482 - softwarecenter.plugin - 
    INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share
    /software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2016-12-13 15:59:49,536 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - 
    INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl
  /aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 166, in open
    self._records = apt_pkg.PackageRecords(self._cache)
SystemError: E:Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists
/www.hu.freepascal.org_lazarus_dists_lazarus-stable_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
 - open (13: Permission denied)
2016-12-13 15:59:49,820 - softwarecenter.db.update - 
    WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/videoplayer.py:29: 
  PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use 
  gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right 
  version gets loaded.
    from gi.repository import Gst
2016-12-13 15:59:50,102 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Comment: Hmm, It seems that my sudo apt-get update is showing a lot of errors, maybe this wasn't working because it can't fetch it?

Comment: sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease [2,842 B]           
Err:3 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i 
appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose
```

and

```
appstreamcli status
```

Wait a few seconds and Open the software center again

If you still get errors try the following:

```
exec sudo -i
apt purge gnome-software ubuntu-software
apt autoremove
apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get clean
```

And open the software center.

Comment: From the first method I got:

          The program 'and' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt install and

Unknown option --verboseappstreamcli
Run 'appstreamcli --help' to see a full list of available command line options.

Comment: on the second thing, after I did the purge and then the autoremove I tried the install and it says: Package gnome-software is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-software' has no installation candidate

Comment: after fixing an error in my apt-get I can now open ubuntu software center if I do it from terminal using sudo

Comment: @Joseph: I edited the post to make it clear, I apologize for being confused my po

Answer (score 1):

In the command line do the following

DO THESE IN THE ORDER LISTED!

sudo apt-get purge software-center

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install software-center

If that does not work do

sudo apt-get update

Comment: E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate